# Can't send the request to the server

Tags: php, ios, ssl, curl, php-7

I've some problem with the PHP script. So, I'm trying to connect to the FMI Server, but when I'm enter a valid credentials the server always return HTTP code 330, instead of 200 OK. Also when I'm trying with invalid credentials it's return 401 and it's okay, but why I've this problem only with VALID credentials? 
What I'm tried?

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
```

But no luck :(

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$username = "callibra@yandex.ru"; //Valid login
$password = "callibra4App"; //Valid Password
class FMIWebApplication {
    private $client = array(
        "user-agent" => "FindMyiPhone/472.1 CFNetwork/711.1.12 Darwin/14.0.0",
        "headers" => array(
                "X-Apple-Realm-Support" => "1.0",
                "X-Apple-Find-API-Ver" => "3.0",
                "X-Apple-AuthScheme" => "UserIdGuest",
                "X-Apple-I-MD-RINFO" => "17106176",
                "Accept" => "*/*",
                "Connection" => "keep-alive",
                "Accept-Encoding" => "br, gzip, deflate",
                "Accept-Language" => "en-us",
                "X-Apple-I-TimeZone" => "GMT+2",
                "X-Apple-I-Locale" => "en_US"
                )
);
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $devices = array();

    public function __construct($username, $password) {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->authenticate();
    }

    public function authenticate() {
        $url = "https://fmipmobile.icloud.com/fmipservice/device/".$this->username."/initClient";
        list($headers, $body) = $this->curlPOST($url, "", $this->username.":".$this->password);
        /*
        if ($headers["http_code"] == 200) {
            return 200;
        };
        if ($headers["http_code"] == 401) {
            return 401;
        };
        if ($headers["http_code"] == 403) {
            return 403;
        };*/
        echo $headers["http_code"];
    }


    private function curlPOST($url, $body, $authentication = "") {
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);                                                              
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->client["user-agent"]);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
        if (strlen($authentication) > 0) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $authentication);  
        }
        $arrHeaders = array();
        $arrHeaders["Content-Length"] = strlen($request);
        foreach ($this->client["headers"] as $key=>$value) {
            array_push($arrHeaders, $key.": ".$value);
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $arrHeaders);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
        $responseBody = substr($response, $header_size);
        $headers = array();
        foreach (explode("\r\n", substr($response, 0, $header_size)) as $i => $line) {
            if ($i === 0)
                $headers['http_code'] = $info["http_code"];
            else {
                list ($key, $value) = explode(': ', $line);
                if (strlen($key) > 0)
                    $headers[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        return array($headers, json_decode($responseBody, true));
    }
}
$API = new FMIWebApplication($username, $password);
$API->authenticate();
?>
```

That's what I'm getting from the server:

```
HTTP/1.1 330 Server: AppleHttpServer/70a91026 Date: Thu, 07 Mar 2019 13:23:40 GMT Content-Length: 0 Connection: keep-alive X-Responding-Instance: fmipservice:34000504:mr23p40ic-ztdg08174101:7004:1903B41:738abffa X-Responding-Server: mr23p40ic-ztdg08174101_004 X-Responding-Partition: p40 X-Apple-MMe-Host: p40-fmipmobile.icloud.com X-Apple-MMe-Scope: 639524741 Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains Set-Cookie: NSC_q40-gnjqtfswjdf=6ad0a3dee1e78d9bd168cb5a7ceafc289128c7a38269b4bddde70dac09e4e273e5f12331;path=/;secure;httponly via: icloudedge:mc10p01ic-zteu01141501:7401:18RC846:Manchester X-Apple-Request-UUID: 8d5dc207-f1f8-453f-8863-9e0d5ab3b58b access-control-expose-headers: X-Apple-Request-UUID access-control-expose-headers: Via 330
```

Comment: what's your curl output?

Comment: 330 is a very unusual status code. Have you asked icloud support (or FMI if they're a separate entity) what it might mean when their server returns this? (P.S. I'd guess you get 401 with invalid credentials - which is the correct response - rather than 330 because the credential test occurs before whatever code is resulting in the 330, and therefore that code never runs as it errors out of the authentication)

Comment: And when you get this status code, does it still return the expected content in the response, or not? You didn't mention that. It would be useful if it returned some sort of explanation along with the code.

Comment: ADyson, nope, it's not returning anything, just a http code 330. That's all what getting...

Comment: I don't see where in the code you actually try to echo the body though? Also if json_decode failed for any reason it would still show null even then. Perhaps you should add an echo of the raw response from curl